# Dynamically partition a 2d tensor into multiple tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Given a 2d tensor (matrix), I would like to partition it into several small ones with equal size. You can regard it as the preprocessing of the max pooling. For instance,

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Given the a dynamic `desired_size` of 2 * 4, the outputs should be:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5

5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9

3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7

7 8 9 10 
8 9 10 11
```

I have studied `slice` and `gather` for a while. But I still don't have idea how to do it. Could you tell me how to get that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tf.extract_image_patches`, even though it turns out somewhat verbose:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(np.arange(8) + np.arange(1,5)[:,np.newaxis])
e = tf.extract_image_patches(x[tf.newaxis,:,:,tf.newaxis],
    [1, 2, 4, 1], [1, 2, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
e = tf.reshape(e, [-1, 2, 4])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
e.eval()

# returns
# array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [ 2,  3,  4,  5]],
#        [[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
#         [ 6,  7,  8,  9]],
#        [[ 3,  4,  5,  6],
#         [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],
#        [[ 7,  8,  9, 10],
#         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```

Comment: I wonder whether is the shape can be dynamic in this method? Thx!

Comment: I don't think it can, you must know the size of our output during graph construction. This is usually the case. If you have a problem with variable tensor dimensions at run time I would be interested to hear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, I need to deal with the case that the `desired_size` is dynamic, do you have any idea about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tied with `tf.split()`:

```
num_splits = 2
desired_size = (2, 4)
A = tf.constant(a)

C = tf.concat(tf.split(A, desired_size[0], 0),1)
D = tf.reshape(tf.concat(tf.split(C, num_splits*desired_size[0], 1), 0), (-1, desired_size[0], desired_size[1]))

#The result
[[[ 1  2  3  4]
[ 2  3  4  5]]

[[ 5  6  7  8]
[ 6  7  8  9]]

[[ 3  4  5  6]
[ 4  5  6  7]]

[[ 7  8  9 10]
[ 8  9 10 11]]]

# For num_splits = 4, desired_size = (2, 2) you get 
[[[ 1  2]
[ 2  3]]

[[ 3  4]
[ 4  5]]

[[ 5  6]
[ 6  7]]

[[ 7  8]
[ 8  9]]

[[ 3  4]
[ 4  5]]

[[ 5  6]
[ 6  7]]

[[ 7  8]
[ 8  9]]

[[ 9 10]
[10 11]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your this one is quite promising to the dynamic `desired_size`. But I tried your code and receive this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. It points to this line of code`C = tf.concat(tf.split(A, desired_height, 0),1)` where `desired_height` is a scalar variable. Do you have any idea to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: For instance, change the definition of `desired_size` to `desired_size=tf.placeholders(tf.int32, (2), name='desired_size')` and keep else the same. And see whether it still works

Comment: How will that work. U now want a tensor to be used to split another tensor?

Comment: Yes cause I want to split it dynamically.

Comment: oh.. i didn't see it anywhere in your question. May be you want to update the question to using tensor to split another tensor.

Comment: Sorry I didn;t make it clear. Now I edited the question. I have worked on it half a day. Seems that Tensorflow doesn't support it now....

Comment: yes there are some issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638 . Ill update if i figure out something.